# How to check for multiple attributes in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a TBRPG game using Python 2.7, and i'm currently making a quest system. I wanted to make a function that checks all of the quests in a list, in this case (`quests`), and tells you if any of of the quests in the list have the same ID or name, and if they do `multiple_id` and `multiple_names` will go up by 1.

```
class Quest:
    def __init__(self, target, name, ID, required_level, objective_requirements, reward_gold, reward_exp, reward_item):
        self.target = target
        self.name = name
        self.ID = ID
        self.req_level = required_level
        self.objective_default = 0
        self.objective_req = objective_requirement
        self.reward_gold = reward_gold
        self.reward_exp = reward_exp
        self.reward_item = reward_item

    def accept(self):
        if self.target.level >= self.req_level:
            self.target.quest.append(self.ID)
        else:
            pass

    def turn_in(self):
        if self.reward_exp >= 0:
            self.target.exp += self.reward_exp
            print '...'
        if self.reward_gold >= 0:
            self.target.gold += self.reward_gold
            print '...'
        if self.reward_item == None:
            pass
        else:
            self.target.inventory.append(self.reward)
            print '...'

def test_quests(list):
    multiple_id = 0
    multiple_names = 0
    for x in list[:]:
        print 'ID ' + str(x.ID)
        print 'Name ' + x.name
        print 'Target ' + str(x.target)
        print 'Required Level ' + str(x.req_level)
        print 'Objective Default ' + str(x.objective_default)
        print 'Objective Requirement ' + str(x.objevtive_req)
        print 'Reward Gold ' + str(x.reward_gold)
        print 'Reward Exp ' + str(x.reward_exp)
        print 'Reward Item' + str(x.reward_item)

    print "Multiple ID's found = %d" % multiple_id
    print "Multiple Name's found = %d" % multiple_names

me = 'Just a filler ATM...'
Quest1 = Quest(me, 'A Simple Task', 001, 0, 1, 100, 20, None)
Quest2 = Quest(me, 'A Difficult Task', 702, 0 , 1, 0 ,0, None)

quests = [Quest1, Quest2]
test_quests(quests)
```

I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: What did you try exactly? Also, don't use `list` as the name of a variable, since it is the same name of the built-in method `list()`.

Comment: why use `[:]` in the `for` loop? Where did you check the ID or name? you just print them

Comment: You should consider reading about "separation of concerns", it will help you in the future to think about it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `set` holding the different IDs and then compare the size of that set to the total number of quests. The difference tells you how many IDs are duplicated. Same for names.

Something like this (untested):

```
def test_quests(quests):
    num_total = len(quests)
    different_ids = len(set((q.ID for q in quests)))
    different_names = len(set((q.name for q in quests)))
    print "Multiple ID's found = %d" % (num_total - different_ids)
    print "Multiple Name's found = %d" % (num_total - different_names)
```

Also, it might be a good idea to implement `Quest.__repr__` and/or `Quest.__str__`, so you just have to do `print some_quest` to print all the details of that quest.

Comment: Thank you, this isn't exactly what I wanted, but it's close enough.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was on my part, the code works fine now. I now have it working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get the amount of duplicated ID/name:

```
id_set = set(map(lambda x: x.ID, quests))
name_set = set(map(lambda x: x.name, quests))
multiple_id = len(quests) - len(id_set)
multiple_names = len(quests) - len(name_set)
```

If you wanna get the existing times of each ID/name, you can use [collection.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of *set* in above code

Answer (score 0):

Your Quest class looks like a [god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

```
class Quest:
    def __init__(self, target, name, ID, required_level, objective_requirements, reward_gold, reward_exp, reward_item):
```

Look at how many inputs it takes.

You should try to isolate its concerns and split it out into more classes.

A class should have only one concern.

Maybe you should break out reward to a separate class.

Also breaking out the objective requirements to a separate class could make sense. Or even, one class for a requirement, then make objective requirements a list of requirements simply.

Thus, you can state that all requirements in the list needs to be met. But each requirement can contain alternate requirements, such as, Give Item A to person A or to person B. Letting the requirement class handle the or, and the quest class handle the and.

Once you have gotten the Quest class down, you should create a [QuestFactory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), which creates quests and creating a quest should check that there is no other quest with the same id or the same name, or count that there are multiple etc.

If you absolutely want to count the occurences of the same id/name, don't reinvent the wheel, use a python mathematical library like pandas or something similar.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame("ID":[x.id for x in quests], "Name":[x.name for x in quests])
print df.ID.value_counts()
print df.Name.value_counts()
```